# Are there any unminify tools for shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, source-code

Various minifier scripts exist for shell code, (e.g. [bash-minifier](http://bash-minifier.appspot.com/)), but how about the reverse?

1. Are there **any** *shell*-centric utils or scripts to automatically turn a one-liner like this:

   ```
   echo foo;echo bar;echo "baz;bing";echo 'buz;bong'
   ```

   ...into this:

   ```
   echo foo
   echo bar
   echo "baz;bing"
   echo 'buz;bong'
   ```
2. Or turn minimalist logic like this:

   ```
   true && echo foo
   ```

   ...into this:

   ```
   if true ; then
       echo foo
   fi
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minification is not generally a reversible operation, as information could be lost in the process, e.g. consider human-readable variable names, comments, logical constructs, which can be written in multitude of different ways e.t.c.

But there are various tools, which can pretty-print or beautify your code,
which should solve *#1* for you.

One example is: https://github.com/mvdan/sh

> A shell parser, formatter and interpreter (POSIX/Bash/mksh)

Running your one-liner, through it, produces the following result:

```
%shfmt <<<"echo foo;echo bar;echo \"baz;bing\";echo 'buz;bong'"

echo foo
echo bar
echo "baz;bing"
echo 'buz;bong'
```

Comment: Progress... but `shfmt` doesn't seem to unroll a `for` loop: `shfmt <<< "for f in foo bar; do echo $f ; done"` returns `for f in foo bar; do echo bar; done` where the semicolons aren't changed into carriage returns.

Comment: @agc It does re-format the loops in fact, but only if they have > 1 statements in the body block, e.g. `shfmt -s <<< "for f in foo bar; do echo $f; echo $f ; done"`